# What is the meaning of "extradistant" in this context?

Tags: quantum-interpretations

This the context. In his book [The Outer Limits of Reason](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/outer-limits-reason) Noson Yanofsky says:

> There are, however, disadvantages to hidden variables that have kept most
>   physicists away. For example, the equations and the mechanism of the hidden
>   variables (pilot waves) are ugly. They are not simple equations that give simple
>   answers. Rather, they are equations that take into account many nonlocal phenomena.

([Google Books link here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ofzfAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT252&lpg=PT252&dq=%22There%20are,%20however,%20disadvantages%20to%20hidden%20variables%20that%20have%20kept%20most%20physicists%20away%22&source=bl&ots=qGfJw_3jSc&sig=ACfU3U1WyFYV3MkfL5jxAwPFaF_KN9kZ-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi83MecgZ7iAhWSGuwKHdp0CO8Q6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22There%20are%2C%20however%2C%20disadvantages%20to%20hidden%20variables%20that%20have%20kept%20most%20physicists%20away%22&f=false))

Even with this **extradistant** information, it is not easy to calculate what the outcomes will be. They are like some of the systems we met in section 7.1. Even though the laws are deterministic, they will not be much help in making anything predictable. That is, just because the particles know where to go does not mean we will be able to predict where they go.

Can anyone say what is the meaning of extradistant? is it like "far away" or is it a term?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the term *extradistant* is not a standard one in pilot wave theory. I suspect it is a term Yanofsky has made up. From the context it means non-local influences on the evolution of the quantum system.

Comment: yeah. it makes sense but it's weird why he didn't actually use the non-local. for that matter, gives this feeling that maybe it has another meaning.